# For positive real numbers $a,b,c$ prove that $ \sum \limits_{cyc}{\frac{a^3}{(a+b)(a+c)}}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{4}$

Tags: inequality

I did this inequality with **Holder Inequality** in this way
\begin{align*}&\left(\sum \limits_{cyc}{\frac{a^3}{(a+b)(a+c)}}\right) \left(\sum \limits_{cyc} (a+b)\right)\left(\sum \limits_{cyc}(a+c)\right)\geq (a+b+c)^3\\
\implies &\sum \limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{(a+b)(a+c)} \geq  \frac{a+b+c}{4}
\end{align*}

Though i did this but it seems to me that it can be done in elementary way. But i can't find that way.

Can you please do this inequality in elementary way?

**Edit:** Please use only AM-Gm and Cauchy-Schwarz(Would be great if you don't use Cauchy-Schwarz)

Comment: By AM-GM, $\frac{a^3}{(a+b)(a+c)}+\frac{a+b}{8}+\frac{a+c}{8}\ge \frac{3a}{4}$. Can you finish it now?

Comment: Yeah i can ok thanks

Comment: The accepted answer is in the comment done by @Ankoganit

Answer (score 2):

By Titu's lemma we get

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{(a+b)(a+c)}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{\frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{a}}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{a}}$$

Now $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{a}=3(a+b+c)+\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ca}{b}$$

Br rearrangement inequality
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{ab}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a^2}\implies(a+b+c)\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{c}$$

Then we get

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{a}\leq4(a+b+c)$$

Then we get

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{(a+b)(a+c)}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{4}$$

Comment: I said elementary way. You used Titu's Lemma, Rearrangement Inequality those are very high level inequalities. Holder Inequality is too high level

Comment: But I think Holder's inequality is deeper than Titu's lemma and rearrangement inequality.

Comment: Yeah that is why i told you that holder is also high level but i don't want to use any high level inequalities. Just assume it is for an olympiad answer

Comment: Both Titu's lemma (which is a simple consequence of C-S) and rearrangement inequality are definitely elementary.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is the same as
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}4a^3(b+c)\ge(a+b+c)(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$$
which is the same as
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}3a^3(b+c)\ge
\sum_{\text{cyc}}4a^2bc+\sum_{\text{cyc}}2a^2b^2$$
which you can get by adding multiples of inequalities of the form
$$ab^3+ac^3\ge ab^2c+abc^2,$$
$$a^3b+ab^3\ge2a^2b^2$$
and their cyclic shifts.